# Jquery Ui range slider with tooltips not taking min value 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I found this jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jL044k1c/81/)

I want the min value to be 0. But as soon I give it a min value of 0, the value 0 is not visible.Also if I give steps to it,then it directly deducts that much from the max value. Can someone please help me out?

```
function slide(event, ui) {
    // Allow time for exact positioning
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(ui.handle).attr('title', ui.value).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
    }, 0);
}
function create(event, ui, start, end) {
    var handles = $(event.target).find('span');
    handles.eq(0).tooltip({
        animation: false,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: handles.eq(0),
        title: start
    }).tooltip('show');
    handles.eq(1).tooltip({
        animation: false,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: handles.eq(1),
        title: end
    }).tooltip('show');
}
$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    values: [1, 100],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        slide(event, ui)
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        create(event, ui, $(this).slider('values', 0), $(this).slider('values', 1))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like This

```
$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
    slide(event, ui)
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.You can try it on the fiddle link.The min value just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/jL044k1c/130/

```
function slide(event, ui) {
    // Allow time for exact positioning
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(ui.handle).attr('title', ui.value).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
    }, 0);
}
function create(event, ui, start, end) {
    var handles = $(event.target).find('span');

    handles.eq(0).tooltip({
        animation: false,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: handles.eq(0),
        title: start
    }).tooltip('show');
    handles.eq(1).tooltip({
        animation: false,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: handles.eq(1),
        title: end
    }).tooltip('show');
}
$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        slide(event, ui)
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {

        create(event, ui, $(this).slider('values', 0), $(this).slider('values', 1))
    }
});
<div id="slider"></div>
body {
    padding: 100px;
}
.ui-slider-handle {
    outline: none;
}
```

But it has a glitch, for first time tooltip is not appearing for "0" value.

Comment: Im using the same fiddle for reference.It has two problems 1- Min value 0 not appearing and secondly if you give it a step property ,it deducts that much from max value.

Comment: Well step property is working fine as desired, please check at "http://jsfiddle.net/jL044k1c/150/". And for min value 0 is not appearing till the time you haven't slided it. Use slider to navigate then you will be able to see 0 too. Issue is the above fiddle is using mix of jquery-ui slider and bootstrap to create tooltip(the black box where slider range is displayed). so Bootstrap tooltip is not getting created.

Comment: The problem is the 0 just doesnt appear till clicked.I want it to be there.Also if i increase the min value from 0 to  1,the min value then appears.Secondly,the step property only works when the min value is 0.If the minimum value is increased and then you give the step property,you will see how it deducts that much from the max value.